# Get selected RadioButton from custom AlertDialog called from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

From a Fragment class I am creating a custom AlertDialog containing 2 radiogroups. My app launches and runs ok but always updates my Fragment TextViews (tvSelectedA & B) with the default RadioButton selections in each RadioGroup - it seems to ignore any selections I make. This is the method called on a button onClickListener on the Fragment:

```
    private void showAlertDialog(View view) {
        final View dialogView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);
        final RadioGroup radioGroupA = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.rgA);
        final RadioGroup radioGroupB = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.rgB);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
        alertBuilder.setView(R.layout.layout_dialog)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // get selected radio button from radioGroup
                        int selectedA = radioGroupA.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                        int selectedB = radioGroupB.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                        // find the radiobutton by returned id
                        radioButtonA = dialogView.findViewById(selectedA);
                        radioButtonB = dialogView.findViewById(selectedB);
                        tvSelectedA.setText(String.format("Selected A: %s", radioButtonA.getTag().toString()));
                        tvSelectedB.setText(String.format("Selected B: %s", radioButtonB.getTag().toString()));
                    }
                });
        alertBuilder.show();
    }
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: `alertBuilder.setView(R.layout.layout_dialog)` – That is telling the `Builder` to inflate that layout itself, so your `View dialogView` and the `RadioGroup`s therein are not what you are seeing in the `AlertDialog`. Pass your `dialogView` to that method instead of that `R.layout`.

Comment: Wow, that did it. Thanks!